# Copy data from one table to another and change datatype

Tags: mysql

Hello I would like to copy data from one table to another table but I would like to convert a varchar column to a integer column the table columns are below I would like to convert the pop column to integer.  Thank You

```
ea_id  int,
yr    int,
age   varchar,
sex   varchar,
eattain   varchar,
income  varchar,
pop varchar, 

--I just created another table and tried loading data like this, my new  
--table has a pop data type of integer, I am still getting a syntax error


load data infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads   
/file.csv'

into table ca_pop.educ_att
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
ignore 1 lines

(ea_id, @yr, age, sex, eattain,income, @pop)

set year = YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(@year,'%m/%d/%Y %k:%i'))
set pop =nullif(pop,'')
);
```

Comment: Like `INSERT INTO anothertable SELECT ea_id, yr, age, sex, eattain, income, CAST(pop as int) FROM onetable;`?

Comment: Either `sql` or `mysql` tag please?

Comment: it is mysql @alex

Comment: MySQL will do the conversion automatically, you don't need to use `CAST()`, although you can if you want.

Comment: What problem did you have when you tried to do it?

Comment: Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: ' ' for column 'population_count' at row 1 @Barmar

Comment: The first row of pop is null

Comment: Originally I just tried to load the data but I was getting error code 1366 so then I created another table and loaded as varchar then I tried to copy to another table but I am still getting error 1366 when I tried to copy

Comment: What should be stored for the null row?

Comment: If you need to perform conditionals when loading data from a csv, you can use temporary variables. The documentation shows examples of this.

Comment: @Barmar if is null, it can be null

Comment: An empty string is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: If you want to empty string to convert to null, use `NULLIF(pop, '')`